# No me funciona mat-paginator con angular material. No hace nada

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table, mat-paginator

Tengo un problema con la paginación en el mat-table.

He estado revisando los comentarios que habéis ido poniendo pero nada me ha solucionado el problema.

Resulta que me pone todo lo que me trae del array sin paginar como aparece en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y tengo dentro de

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.particionesService.translateMatPaginator(this.paginator);
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
}
```

También tengo dentro de

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
}
```

Y fuera del constructor tengo declarado `DataSource:any` junto con el array y las columnas y el paginator:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

dataSource: any;

displayedColumns: string[] = ["Marca", "Ver planograma"];

planogramas:any = [
{ Marca: "Apiserum", Planograma: "www......" },
{ Marca: "XLS", Planograma: "www......" },
{ Marca: "XLS", Planograma: "www......" },
{ Marca: "XLS", Planograma: "www......" },
{ Marca: "XLS", Planograma: "www......" },
{ Marca: "XLS", Planograma: "www......" },
{ Marca: "XLS", Planograma: "www......" },
]
```

Decir que tengo los import en el archivo module (Tanto MatTableModule como MatPaginatorModule), y en los componentes también. Tengo un archivo module que me coge todos los componentes y en las declaraciones del module tengo los componentes donde en varios de ellos quiero usar el mat-table y en un componente me lo hace bien y en el otro no.

Comment: Cómo y donde estas inicializando el `datasource`?

Comment: para que funcione matpaginator necesitas que tu tipo de datos de talba sea matTableDatasource. importa el modulo:  `import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';` y tu dataSource deberia se de tipo matTableDataSource:  `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();`. despues agrega el contenido a tu datasource usando la propiedad 'data': `this.dataSource.data = this.planogramas`;